# Does Axis plugin in Eclipse uses AdminClient to deploy Web Services?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, deployment, axis

Does Axis plugin in Eclipse uses AdminClient to deploy Web Services? I am changing my deploy.wsdd file under WEB_INF/some/name/space/deploy.wsdd and nothing happens. I am even able to deploy invalid XML in this file. How can I force Eclipse to use it when deploying Web Services?

Answer (score 1):

If Web Service should be deployed using deploy.wsdd then you must use org.apache.axis.client.AdminClient class.

```
java org.apache.axis.client.AdminClient deploy.wsdd
```